# Step Back Key in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-developer-tools

When debugging JavaScript with Chrome Developer Tools, I can step forward into code by pressing the F11 key. Is there a way I can do the opposite, take a step backward? I tried pressing Shift + F11 but that steps out of the function altogether.

Comment: There's no such thing. Have you ever seen any debugger supporting it?

Comment: @wOxxOm It's called "time travel debugging" and multiple environments support it (including ChakraCore for JS) so it's an absolutely reasonable question to ask.